# Is it possible to have Java listen to multiple RabbitMQ queues?

Tags: java, messaging, rabbitmq

I suspect this is possible but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do it.  I went through the tutorials on rabbitmq's site and they were really helpful and did what I wanted except it didn't show how to listen to multiple queues in the same program.

My program structure is basically a few phases..for example, phase 1 gathers a lot of data and then phase 2 processes it and loads it in a database, phase 3 analyzes it against other data, etc..Each phase cannot start until the previous phase is done and I wanted to use a queue system to use multiple machines to finish each phase quicker(so all consumers work on phase1 then once all of them are done, they go and work on phase 2 together,etc).

I think I can't just do each phase once because the queue could be empty and the computer would move to the next queue and I have no way of knowing if its empty because all the work is done or if its done because we haven't started putting work in the queue yet.  So I thought (correct me if I'm wrong) a better way was to listen to all queues associated with all phases and as work gets put into phase1Queue it works on it and if work gets put into phase2Queue it works on it right after (I have another processes outside of the process I'm describing that monitors when each phase is done and sets up for the next phase).

The code in the queue sample is helpful for a consumer listening to one queue but how can I make it listen to multiple (and call different programs depending on different queues).  If there's a function for this already then awesome but I'm kind of looking for the logic I can use to implement this in Java (worst case I have thought of running 5 separate programs listening to each queue but I'm trying to find out if there's a better way, having one application with all my work in it would make managing distribution easier).

p.s. here's the consumer code that works for [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) (but as you can see it only defines one queue):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;

public class Worker {

  private static final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";

  public static void main(String[] argv)
                      throws java.io.IOException,
                      java.lang.InterruptedException {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

    channel.basicQos(1);

    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

    while (true) {
      QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
      String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

      System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");   
      doWork(message); 
      System.out.println(" [x] Done" );

      channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

### Update

I thought my explanation may be too verbose so I think a simple way of thinking of what I'm trying to do is: I have multiple worker nodes that I want to utilize them for different tasks (and those different tasks come from different queues). Currently I only know how to make them listen to a single queue which is associated to a single type of work but I want them to listen to different queues so as different work comes up the same cluster of nodes can handle them.

### Update

As per comment, the coordinator process is super simple.  Its just a program that monitors from Phase1Queue and once that queue is empty it simply starts a process to fill up Phase2Queue, etc.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with RabbitMQ, but isn't this a matter of creating multiple consumers, one per queue? But it's not clear how you will move each machine from phase1 to phase2 (presumably using your coordinator). Why not use a single queue and tag the tasks so that the recipient can tell what to do with it (i.e. which phase the task is for)?

Comment: @DNA Thank you! Thats actually a good idea, I didn't think about it but that could work.  My coordinator program will need to keep track of what phase its in but other than that it would also be easy to add/remove phases in my main program.  I'm just not sure if its possible to send multiple arguments with rabbitmq but i'll start looking it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to separate the different phases in to different modules/services/processes and have all of them running concurrently.

Each phase's consumer listens to a different queue. Each phase is responsible for producing messages for the next phase's queue.

This way you have reduced complexity by having single responsibilities. Each process consumes from a particular queue and produces for another queue. You can then, if need be, scale these separate processes up and/or out.

This is a pattern that we use. We have an initial job from which up to 100 times more sub jobs are ultimately created. The initial jobs are very small and quick to run whereas the sub jobs are potentially long-running requests which we service with a small army of cloud instances. These jobs then return their results via another queue, the results of which are then collated and added to a database.